# How to filter in a batch query on dates

Tags: apex, string, schedulebatch, global-variables

I have a soql query in a batch process where I want to filter on dates. I currently get the error: First error: unexpected token: Start_Date__c. How do I advoid this?

Apex

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(

    'SELECT Id, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, Account__c, New_Address__r.BillingStreet__c, New_Address__r.BillingPostalCode__c' +
    'New_Address__r.BillingCity__c, New_Address__r.BillingState__c, Recordtype FROM New_Account_Address__c' +
    'Account__r.BillingStreet' +
    'WHERE Start_Date__c < TODAY AND End_Date__c > TODAY'
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is no space currently between the end of `Account__r.BillingStreet` and the beginning of `WHERE...`

Try adding a space there.

Comment: +1; there's a couple other syntax errors that will appear when that's fixed (missing space, missing comma, incorrect field name `Recordtype`)

Comment: @DavidReed Thanks I just realized that